# CrossThread error with Parallel class - ProgressBar

Tags: c#, progress-bar, multithreading

I'm executing a lot of inserts and I want to add a progress bar.  Using Parallel ForEach, I get the following error:

> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException"
>
> progressbar1 a levé une exception de type  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text = richTextBox1.Lines.Length.ToString(); 
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timediff = new TimeSpan();

    progressBar1.Maximum = i;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    int j = 1;
    l = 0;
    k=0;
    Parallel.ForEach(richTextBox1.Lines, (line) =>
    {
        progressBar1.Value = j;
        try
        {
            string pwd = query.Querie_read("select plain from rainbow where plain='" + line.ToString() + "'");
            if (pwd != line.ToString())
            {
                fct.AddRainbow(line.ToString());
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                l++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            l++;
        }

        j++;

    });
    textBox1.Text = k.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = l.ToString();
    timediff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);
    textBox2.Text = timediff.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
}
```

Comment: In addition to the issues of talking to the UI (not allowed), your use of `j`, `k` and `l` is itself has deep issues when using parallel threads. Plus, making [n] parallel database calls should be replaced by a SINGLE database call using IN. Also, your SQL approach is ripe for SQL injection, which is a very bad thing (should be parameterised). And swallowing exceptions. In fact, pretty much every line inside your `Parallel` usage has *some* problem, in some way. I would provide better options, but I'm not sure I like the sound of rainbow table password-lookups.

Comment: it's just a temporary form to add 1.7 million words
It's just for my end of year uni project, i'm not interested in hacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate() { progressBar1.Value = j; }))
```

Answer (score 1):

UI can only be updated from the main thread (or more precisely, the thread that created the UI). To execute your code in the right thread, use the dispatcher:

For WPF:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = j));
```

For WinForm:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = j));
```

Comment: I get this  error : Impossible to convert a lambda expression to a type 'System.Delegate', because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I had a look around again and found the answer this time :

 progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate()
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = j;
                }));

Comment: Sorry, I edited my message. You just have to explicitely instanciate an Action object with the lambda and it should work.

Comment: I get this error now : 
The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x4c4478 to COM context 0x4c45e8 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single...
I'm just going to stick to the other solution
Thanks for your help anyway